# File.getCanonicalPath() failure examples

Tags: java, file-io

Does anyone have an experience or know when the method `File.getCanonicalPath()` will throw an `IOException`

I have tried to look up from the Internet and the best answer is in [File API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29) which says

"`IOException` - If an I/O error occurs, which is possible because the construction of the canonical pathname may require filesystem queries"

However, it is not clear to me because I still cannot think of a case which this might fail. Can anyone give me concrete examples which can happen on Linux, Windows and other OS (optional)?

I reason I want to know is because I want to handle this exception accordingly. Thus, it will be best if I know all the possible failures that can happen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a Windows example:

Try calling `getCanonicalFile` on a file in your CD-drive, but without a CD loaded. For example:

```
new File("D:\\dummy.txt").getCanonicalFile();
```

you will get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The device is not ready
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:396)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:559)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:583)
```

Comment: Does it mean if the file does not exist this method will fail or does it only fail for removable drive? Also, @LaGrandMere said that it was fixed in Java 1.5? So this example isn't the case anymore?

Comment: @gigadot : give it a try by yourself, but I think that it will raise the IOExpcetion. My example was about a bug that was fixed, but the example given should always throw an IOException, that's why I put a +1 on it :)

Comment: They say the bug has been fixed, but it fails for me on 1.6.0_21.

Comment: Thank you @LaGrandMere. +1 for both of you for quick and accurate reply. I will wait a bit to see if anyone can give me more examples before accpeting the answer but this is the best so far.

Comment: @dogbane : ah ? funny :) @gigadot : thanks, I think you won't get better answer than dogbane's one which is excellent :)

Comment: But another answer to this question ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/4490011/545127 ) suggests that was a bug in the JRE.

Comment: Isn't "getCanonicalFile()" kinda redundant because you are already are saying it's a file by saying "new File(...)"? This answer seems to be more specific to quirks of (likely rarely used) getCanonicalFile() rather than what the question asks, which is asking about getCanonicalPath() ?

Answer (score 6):

The IO Exception also occurs if we try creating a File object with Windows device file keywords (see [device files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Device_files)) used as file name.
As if you try renaming the file to those keywords, Windows will not let you to make it (no CON, PRN, COM1 etc. file names allowed), Java also won't be able to convert that file name to the correct path.

So, any of next next code will trow the IO Exception:

```
File file = new File("COM1").getContextPath();
File file = new File("COM1.txt").getContextPath();
File file = new File("C:/somefolder/COM1.txt").getContextPath();
```

However, next code should work:

```
File file = new File("COM1_.txt").getContextPath();  //underscore wins :)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is generic example for all OS:

```
new File("\u0000").getCanonicalFile();
```

Before canonicalizing of the file, its validity is checked with java.io.File#isInvalid:

```
final boolean isInvalid() {
    if (status == null) {
        status = (this.path.indexOf('\u0000') < 0) ? PathStatus.CHECKED
                                                   : PathStatus.INVALID;
    }
    return status == PathStatus.INVALID;
}
```

And if the file is invalid - you'll get an IO exception:

```
public String getCanonicalPath() throws IOException {
    if (isInvalid()) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid file path");
    }
    return fs.canonicalize(fs.resolve(this));
}
```

Profit!

Answer (score 3):

Seen here in the [Sun Bug Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=c542cb827c6c11e985898911305?bug_id=6192278).

For JRE 1.4.2_06, File.getCanonicalPath() wasn't working on Windows for a removable drive when there is no media present in the drive.

It was corrected in Java 1.5, but you can see there can be OS-based problems with this method.

I don't know of any problem in the current time, but it can happen, that's exactly what the Javadoc says. Usually it's quickly fixed in the newest Java version.

Answer (score 3):

One more scenario, When you try to use Operating System restricted/invalid characters as your file name.

For Windows `\ / : * ? " < > |` these are the invalid characters. Try to rename a file with : you will get a balloon/tip message about the invalid characters.

Try the Following Java Code.

```
File file = new File("c:/outputlog-2013-09-20-22:15"); 
//A common scenario when you try to append java.util.Date to create a file like
//File newFile = new File(filename + "_" + new Date());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

If the File name contains 
`* ?` you will get java.io.IOException: Invalid argument 
`| :` you will get java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

when you use the getCanonicalPath() method. 
If we use any of `" < >` 
char in the file name, then getCanonicalPath() method is **not** failing but when you try to create the file you will be getting the Invalid argument Exception.

Refer [jdk7 api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29)

The precise definition of canonical form is system-dependent. Here I have used windows 7.